# Angle calculation between a line and ellipse

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, analytic-geometry

I calculated the angle $\varphi$ between the droplet and the interface and the case where I considered the droplet is a perfect sphere and found the current relation:

$$180 - (2 * \arctan(\frac{d/2}{h}))* \frac{180}{\pi}$$

Now, I want to find the relation in the case where the droplet is an ellipsoid, like the second image.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Like I've commented on your previous post, just knowing $d$ and $h$ is not enough to uniquely describe an ellipse. If you don't have a unique ellipse, it means that you don't have a unique value for angle.

Answer (score 1):

In the figure below, the radius of the interface is the same, and the height above interface is the same. Which is the correct angle? There are infinitely many ellipses that pass through the interface, and have the same height above the interface.

[image: two ellipses]

Comment: so what other measurement I can do to get one solution?

Comment: @Khalil.h There are two approaches: 1. measure the geometry of the ellipse - find the center and get the semiaxes. and 2. calculate the semiaxes (or at least the ratio) using some physical constraints. I don't know your physics well enough to say why an elliptic shape would be more favorable than another.

Comment: in the case where the volume is constant (same as the sphere), can I get the solution with that supplementary information without the need of the semiaxes...?

Comment: @Khalil.h That's an equivalent condition. If you know the radius of the sphere, you can calculate the volume of the ellipsoid in terms of semiaxes, and that will give you the additional equation that you need. But I don't see that this information is part of your original post. You should specify that you start with a sphere, with $h_S$ and $d_S$ parameters, then you keep the volume constant and get $h_E$ and $d_E$ parameters